# Limit of Multivariable Function!

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I've tried solving the following question using the squeeze theorem, changing to polar coordinates, and trying to plug in different values, but I don't seem to be able to prove that the limit exists (or doesn't). How would you go about solving this?
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{xy})}{xy} $$

Comment: Expand in Taylor series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using the limit of the composition of functions... In other words, if you set $w = \sqrt{xy}$, your limit is simply
$$
\lim_{w\to 0^+} \dfrac{1- \cos w}{w^2} = \lim_{w\to 0^+} \frac{\sin w}{2w} = \frac 12.
$$

You must keep in mind that, in the original variables, the limit is taken along the set $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x y \ge 0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! After a long time of not seeing any limits, jumping back into it with two variables has been qutie confusing.